# Why does my Python3 code return an OverflowError?

Tags: python-3.x

I got this example out of a [weird, old book](http://www.abebooks.com/products/isbn/9780131115187/212617707) from the 1970s full of flowcharts and calculus examples. It's not very well-written, but I'm having fun writing the flowcharts into Python and trying to figure out what these equations actually are and how they work.

This particular example claims to represent a linear approximation of the Malthus and Verhulst population growth models. (Caveat lector: I could find no relationship between the equations in my book and the so-called *Verhulst equation* or *logistic function*.)

```
import math

def malthus_verhulst():
    a = int(input("please enter a value for a\n:%"))
    b = int(input("please enter a value for b\n:%"))
    c = int(input("please enter a value for c\n:%"))
    p = []
    v = []
    p1 = float(input("please enter a value for p1\n:%"))
    v1 = float(input("please enter a value for v1\n:%"))
    p.append(p1)
    v.append(v1)
    for k in range(50):
        p.append((1+c)*p[k])
        v.append(v[k]+(a*v[k] - math.pow(b*v[k],2)))
    print(p,v)
```

Is there a way to rewrite this to where it will work for various values of a, b, c, p1, and v1?

```
$ python -i scratchpad.py 
>>> malthus_verhulst()
please enter a value for a
:%2
please enter a value for b
:%2
please enter a value for c
:%2
please enter a value for p1
:%2
please enter a value for v1
:%2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scratchpad.py", line 92, in malthus_verhulst
    v.append(v[k]+(a*v[k] - math.pow(b*v[k],2)))
OverflowError: math range error
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of `v` in an exception handler you'll see that it quickly grows out of bounds, with the last value being -3.1331863238009388e+206. Since squaring a number doubles the exponent, and the maximum exponent for a `float` is about 308, the algorithm blows up. Make sure that your input values are within the domain for the algorithm.